# App killed event in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, kill, kill-process

In a service, I need to do something when a certain running app is being killed using command `killall com.test.test`. I am already listening to events for when the app is being uninstalled, but I cannot find such event for killed processes. Does it exist? my current code looks like this:

```
IntentFilter packageFilter = new IntentFilter();
packageFilter.addDataScheme("package");
packageFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
packageFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED);
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("App", "onReceive");
  }
}, packageFilter);
```

Comment: I think package removed is for uninstall

Comment: yes, that's what I said "I am already listening to events for when the app is being uninstalled"